# Difference between "class A; class B" and "class A::B"

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between:

```
class A
  class B
  end
end
```

and

```
class A
end

class A::B
end
```

---

Update: These 2 approaches are not exactly the same.

In the second approach, `B` doesn't have access to constants defined in `A`.

Also, as Matheus Moreira correctly stated, in the second approach, `A` must be defined before `A::B` can be defined.

What other differences are there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby, modules and classes are instances of the [`Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html) and [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html) classes, respectively. They derive their names from the *constant* they are assigned to. When you write:

```
class A::B
  # ...
end
```

You are effectively writing:

```
A::B ||= Class.new do
  # ...
end
```

Which is valid constant assignment syntax, and *assumes* that the `A` constant has been properly initialized *and* that it refers to a `Module` or a `Class`.

For example, consider how classes are usually defined:

```
class A
  # ...
end
```

What is effectively happening is this:

```
Object::A ||= Class.new do
  # ...
end
```

Now, when you write:

```
class A
  class B
    # ...
  end
end
```

What actually happens looks like this:

```
(Object::A ||= Class.new).class_eval do
  (A::B ||= Class.new).class_eval do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Here's what is happening, in order:

1. A new `Class` instance is asssigned to the `A` constant of `Object`, unless it was already initialized.
2. A new `Class` instance is asssigned to the `B` constant of `A`, unless it was already initialized.

This ensures the existence of *all* outer classes before attempting to define *any* inner classes.

There is also a change in scope, which allows you to directly access `A`'s constants. Compare:

```
class A
  MESSAGE = "I'm here!"
end

# Scope of Object
class A::B
  # Scope of B
  puts MESSAGE  # NameError: uninitialized constant A::B::MESSAGE
end

# Scope of Object
class A
  # Scope of A
  class B
    # Scope of B
    puts MESSAGE  # I'm here!
  end
end
```

According to [this blog post](http://yugui.jp/articles/846), the Ruby core team calls the "current class" the `cref`. Unfortunately, the author does not elaborate, but as he notes, it is separate from the context of `self`.

---

[As explained here](http://ruby2cext.rubyforge.org/limitations.html#section7), the `cref` is a *linked list* that represents the nesting of modules at some point in time.

> The current `cref` is used for constant and class variable lookup and
>   for `def`, `undef` and `alias`.

---

As the others have stated, they are different ways of expressing the same thing.

There is, however, a subtle difference. When you write `class A::B`, you *assume* that the `A` class has already been defined. If it has not, you will get a `NameError` and `B` will not be defined at all.

Writing properly nested modules:

```
class A
  class B
  end
end
```

Ensures the `A` class exists before attempting to define `B`.

Comment: I've updated the question to show that these 2 approaches are not the same.

Comment: @nickh, you don't need to edit the question to include the answers. You should [upvote the answers which were helpful and accept the one which definitely answered your question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: The thing is, none of them answered the question. All of the answers say that the 2 approaches are the same, which they're not.

Comment: @nickh, I have added more details. Please take a look.

Comment: Great explanation of how the constants are defined. Thanks! Any idea why `B` doesn't have access to constants in `A` when `B` is defined using `class A::B` ?

Comment: @nickh, it constant names are apparently not resolved by superclass, but by scope. I've updated my answer once more with details.

Comment: Very well explained. This is important stuff that a lot of Ruby developers don't take the time to learn.

Comment: Epic answer, Matheus. Thanks!

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Why is superclass and scope not the same then?

Answer (score 3):

Two different ways to say the same thing. That thing is that class B is an inner or nested class and can only be accessed through the the A interface.

```
> class A
..  def say
....  "In A"
....end
..
..  class B
....  def say
......  "In B"
......end
....end
..end
=> nil

> A.new.say
=> "In A"
> B.new.say
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant B>
> A::B.new.s­ay
=> "In B"
```

versus

```
> class A
..  def say
....  "In A"
....end
..end
=> nil

> class A::B
..  def say
....  "In B"
....end
..end
=> nil

> A.new.say
=> "In A"
> B.new.say
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant B>
> A::B.new.s­ay
=> "In B"
>
```

Comment: I've updated the question to show that these 2 approaches are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. They are different ways of writing the same thing. The first one is the naive way of writing it, but often, it gets hard to keep track of the nesting once the class/module gets large. Using the second way, you can avoid nesting in the appearance.

Comment: I've updated the question to show that these 2 approaches are not the same.

Comment: @nickh I thought those differences are trivial and presupposed, so I didn't mention them. Pointing them out are not much different from saying "well, the string `class B` looks different from `class A::B`", but you did not mention that.