# Why can't ruby classes inside modules have the same scope as regular classes?

Tags: ruby, scope

I have a module with a class inside, but I find that the class inside can't reach any of the methods in the enclosing module without specifying the module path.

Another way to look at it is that the module_function doesn't seem to carry into the class.

Example:

```
module MyMod
  def meaning
    42
  end

  class Foo
    def initialize
      puts "New Foo"
      puts "I can call #{MyMod.meaning} from here"
      puts "But I can't get to #{meaning} from here"
    end
  end

  def go
    puts "I can get to #{meaning} from here"
    bar = Foo.new
  end

  module_function :go, :meaning
  go
end
```

If you run this, you get an error on the "But I can't..." line of:

```
undefined local variable or method `meaning'
```

But if you remove the MyMod bits around the whole file, it has no problem accessing the outer method.

Is there an easy way to make these accessible without having to give the full path?

(One of the reasons I am nitpicking over not including the full path is because I'm using http://redshift.sourceforge.net/script/ in order to create ruby scripts that I can instantiate - and they don't have a clear and simple name like 'MyMod' that I can just add to the path, I actually have to pass the scope around even though it's just the enclosing scope to the class)

Comment: I've just examined Kernel#binding, but don't see how that's the issue.  I tried passing the binding to Foo and using eval(meaning,scope) but that also didn't work.

Comment: Those are just the rules of scope in Ruby. https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/a-deep-dive-into-ruby-scopes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a module with a class inside,

No, you don't. You have a module *definition* with a class *definition* inside, but that *does not make the class a nested class*. Ruby does *not have nested classes*.

Ruby is not [Beta](https://beta.cs.au.dk/), [Scala](https://scala-lang.org/), or [Newspeak](https://newspeaklanguage.org/), there are no nested classes in Ruby.

Nesting a module or class *definition* inside another module or class definition does *not* create nesting relationship between the two classes / modules. It only makes *the constant* which references the class / module part of the outer class' / module's namespace.

In other words, there is no difference between

```ruby
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

and

```ruby
class Quux
end

module Foo
  Bar = Quux
end
```

*Only* the constant is nested, but *not* the object that is referenced by the constant.

> but I find that the class inside can't reach any of the methods in the enclosing module without specifying the module path.

That is precisely because *there is no "enclosing module"*. There is a *lexically enclosing* module *definition* but that does *not* create any form of relationship whatsoever between the `Foo` class and the `MyMod` module.

> Another way to look at it is that the module_function doesn't seem to carry into the class.

I honestly don't understand what you mean by that, what it means for a method to "carry into a class", but [`Module#module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function) is not magic. It does exactly what the documentation says it does: it takes an instance method of the module, copies it as an instance method of the *singleton class* of the module, and makes the original instance method [`private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private).

You can read [its specification in the Ruby/Spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/module/module_function_spec.rb), it is fairly simple. Also, the [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/) source code, both the [basic version for booting the Rubinius kernel](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/b7a755c83f3dd3f0c1f5e546f0e58fb61851ea44/core/alpha.rb#L659-L674) and the [full version](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/b7a755c83f3dd3f0c1f5e546f0e58fb61851ea44/core/zed.rb#L88-L111) are fairly readable.

In the end, `Module#module_function` really does not do much more than

```ruby
class Module
  def module_function(*meths)
    meths.each do |meth|
      define_singleton_method(meth, &instance_method(meth).bind(self))
      private meth
    end

    self
  end
end
```

> If you run this, you get an error on the "But I can't..." line of:
>
> ```
> undefined local variable or method `meaning'
> ```

The reason is simple: neither the class `Foo` nor any of its superclasses has any method of that name, so *of course* you get an exception.

> But if you remove the MyMod bits around the whole file, it has no problem accessing the outer method.

*There is no "outer method"*. Ruby does not have Beta-like nested classes. That is really the fundamental cause of your misunderstanding. You expect Ruby to behave like Beta, but it just doesn't. Ruby takes inspiration from any languages, most notably (in rough order of importance) Smalltalk, Lisp, Perl, and Clu, but Beta is not among them.

This here works for a completely different reason:

```ruby
def meaning
  42
end

class Foo
  def initialize
    meaning
  end
end
```

Methods that are defined at the top-level are implicitly defined as private instance methods of [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html). This is because the [*default definee* at the top-level is `::Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39455461/2988). Since `Foo` inherits from `Object`, method lookup will eventually find the `meaning` method defined in `Object`.

> Is there an easy way to make these accessible without having to give the full path?

Inheritance. For example, [`Module#append_features`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-append_features), which is called by [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include), makes the module the superclass of the including class, and thus all instance methods of the module become part of the method lookup ancestry chain.

An aside: if there is no nesting, then what does [`Module::nesting`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-nesting) do? Well, yeah, that is an unfortunately named method. The term "nested class" or "nested module" has a well-defined meaning in OO going all the way back to Beta. But this method is about a completely different kind of nesting:

It refers to the *lexical* nesting of module *definitions*, and *not* to nesting of modules *themselves*.

For example, these module definitions all define the *exact same* module, but the definition *text* has different nesting:

```ruby
module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz
      module Qux
        p Module.nesting
        #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar::Baz, Foo::Bar, Foo]
      end
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  module Bar
    module Baz::Qux
      p Module.nesting
      #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar, Foo]
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  module Bar::Baz
    module Qux
      p Module.nesting
      #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar::Baz, Foo]
    end
  end
end

module Foo::Bar
  module Baz
    module Qux
      p Module.nesting
      #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar::Baz, Foo::Bar]
    end
  end
end

module Foo
  module Bar::Baz::Qux
    p Module.nesting
    #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo]
  end
end

module Foo::Bar::Baz
  module Qux
    p Module.nesting
    #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar::Baz]
  end
end

module Foo::Bar
  module Baz::Qux
    p Module.nesting
    #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux, Foo::Bar]
  end
end

module Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux
  p Module.nesting
  #=> [Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux]
end
```

Again, this is purely *lexical* nesting of the module *definition*. The module itself is not nested; the module itself is the same in all of these cases. This nesting *only* affects *constant lookup*.

Constants are looked up [first lexically *outwards* in enclosing module definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34665369/2988), then *upwards* the inheritance chain.

There is another instance where things can be nested: *blocks* create *nested* lexical scopes, whereas all other lexical scopes (script, module / class definition, and method definition) don't nest. In other words, blocks and *only blocks* have access to the local variables (and `self`) of their enclosing lexical scopes.

Comment: Yup - my misunderstanding (not based on Beta but on the presumption that hierarchy actually had meaning beyond namespacing for classes, so be it that it does not).  That makes it easy to figure out a fix, thanks!

Comment: A note on terminology: in OO, *hierarchy* usually refers to an *inheritance* hierarchy (for languages that have inheritance), a *type* hierarchy () for languages that have subtyping, or a delegation chain (for languages that have prototype delegation). What you have here, is *lexical nesting*. And in particular, in Ruby, *lexical nesting* of *definitions* does not (necessarily) create a nesting of *objects*. This is unlike Beta, Newspeak, or Scala, where a nested class becomes a member of instances of the enclosing class, just like methods and instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for the distinction.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Ruby name resolution and method look up works. When you write `x` anywhere, Ruby will, in this order:

1. Look for a `x` local variable
2. Look for a `x` method in `self.class`
3. Look for a `x` method in `self.superclass`
4. Repeat step 3 until `superclass` is `nil`

   Ruby will walk up the class hierarchy
   trying to find the method `x`
   until it reaches `BasicObject`.
5. Invoke `method_missing`

   Its default behavior is to raise the error you encountered.

`MyMod` merely contains `Foo`, it is not part of `Foo`'s class hierarchy. That is why the method cannot not be found.

Comment: "`MyMod` merely contains `Foo`, it is not part of `Foo`'s class hierarchy." – Actually, it doesn't even do *that*. `MyMod` merely contains *the constant* `Foo`, but it does *not* contain the class that is referenced by the constant `Foo`. It appears that the OP is expecting things to work like they do in Beta and Newspeak, but Ruby is not Beta. BTW, I am quite amazed at how many questions there are, where people expect Ruby to behave like Beta; I never knew that there is such a large number of people being familiar with an obscure niche Scandinavian research language from 1992.

Comment: Perhaps it is not that they are all familiar with Beta. Perhaps it is just that Beta's design and behavior are close to what feels most natural and logical to people without deep knowledge about the internals of Ruby?

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're correct, but there is such a thing as module nesting. For example, `class X class Y end end` is distinct from `class X end; class X::Y end` for the purposes of name resolution. That's what I was referring to. [See `Module::nesting`.](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-nesting) I've also [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9741359/512904) about this before.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh, I just saw your answer, you mentioned this in it. Nice.